# Subversion Can't flush file to disk: Input/output error

Tags: svn

The developers on my company can't commit to subversion anymore.

They receive the follow error message in Tortoise.

```
Can't flush file to disk: Input/output error
```

Apache error.log

```
Could not create activity /01_REPO/!svn/act/6a9f9e72-2412-3147-9534-1b23de635229.  [500, #0]
could not begin a transaction  [500, #5]
Can't flush file to disk: Input/output error  [500, #5]
```

a google search led me to permission and disk space issues but everthing under /01_REPO has permission to user and group "apache"

and there is no problem with disk space

```
df -h 
/dev/mapper/vg_svnserver-lv_home
                  191G   12G  169G   7% /01_REPO
```

The subversion log is empty.

Can someone tell me whats is going on or at least give a hint of how to discover the problem?

OBS: 
Oracle Linux 6.6
svnserve 1.6.11
apache 2.2
iptables off
selinux disabled

Comment: What does the syslog say?

Comment: > svnserve 1.6.11 > upgrade your Subversion server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the disk itself, nothing related with subversion.

I tried to use "svnadmin dump" but I can't restore "svnadmin load" so I use svnadmin hotcopy do copy svn repos to another partition.